# Undefined variable in fluent query builder

Tags: mysql, fluent, laravel

I am starting to use the Laravel framework, and I have a problem with the fluent query builder. In a where condition, if I am using raw values or `Input::get()`, it retrieves the results and executes correctly, but when I use an assigned variable it shows "Undefined variable" errors.

```
$properties = Listing::where(function($query)
{
    if (Input::has('property-type')) $query->where('property_type', '=',Input::get('property-type'));
})->get();
```

it  works correctly, but if I do

```
$pt=Input::get('property-type');
$properties = Listing::where(function($query)
{
    if ($pt!='') $query->where('property_type', '=',$pt);
})->get();
```

it returns the error

```
Undefined variable: pt
```

If I print the variable "$pt" it contains the value.

I want to use only the variable values, because I should pass these value from the controller to the model as parameters, and build the query in the model function. Am I doing something wrong? Is the variable not assigned before the query execution? Please, can anyone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are struggling with the variable is because it's outside of the anonymous function's scope.

I wouldn't worry about passing variables to the models to construct the query, simply use the awesome `Input` class methods.

Comment: thank you for you reply.. yes. it is just enough to use only the "Input" class method. but i used PHP's "use" function to resolve this problem. like  Listing::where(function($query) use($pt){..})

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @viji comment, you can do it by utilizing php `use` keyword:

```
$var = 5;
$orgs = app('db')->table('t')
        ->where('status', '=', '1')
        // Sending $var to anonymous function
        ->where(function ($query) use ($var) {
            $query->where('orgs.name', 'like', "%$var%");
        })->select('id')
        ->get();
```